# Laravel foreach Looping Returns Weird Result

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a problem with when I 'm looping through a result set with a relation inside that I am foreach-ing as well.

This is the code currently:

```
<?php

$deadlines = App\Deadlines::where('beginDatum', '<=', date("Y-m-d"))
    ->where('eindDatum', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
    ->first();

$totalActivities = App\UserActivity::where('userid', Auth::id())
    ->where('deadline', '=', $deadlines->id)
    ->count();

if($totalActivities > 0) {
    $activiteiten = \App\User::find(Auth::id());
    foreach ($activiteiten->useractivities as $user_activity) {
        if ($deadlines->id == $user_activity->deadline) {
            print_r("<div class='col-md-4'><input type='text' value='$user_activity->datum' class='form-control'></div>");
            foreach ($user_activity->activity as $activity) {
                print_r("<div class='col-md-7'><input type='text' value='$activity->activiteit' class='form-control'></div>");
            }
            print_r("<div class='col-md-1'><input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Edit'></div>");
        }
    }
} else {
?>

<br/>U heeft nog geen activiteiten toegevoegd!

<?php
}
```

But it has some strange behaviour when there is a duplicate 'activityid' in the 'user_activity' table. For example...

> ```
> |--------------------------------------|
> |  date     |  userid     | activityid |
> |--------------------------------------|
> | 2017-12-28| 1           | 1          |
> | 2017-11-30| 1           | 1          |
> |--------------------------------------|
> ```

It has two of the same activityid's so the name of the activity is the same, but I don't know why it only shows the date of duplicate activities. When there is only one entry of an activityid it shows just fine:
https://gyazo.com/11cc6828f97e7a191bf40c8b74448e83

Comment: Uhhhh.. Where to begin....

Comment: Assuming these are Eloquent models, shouldn't you be using a many-to-many relationship between user activity and deadline?

Comment: Why are you doing `$deadlines = App\Deadlines` and not adding these beneath the namespace and then just run `$deadlines = Deadlines::where()` ?

Comment: It is not about the deadlines, it is about the activities

Comment: Option, ignore the other issues with the code. Just focus on the problem - the way Thimo's approaching Laravel object relationships.

Comment: These are all eloquent models indeed, the user has a many to many relation to user-activities, user-activities has a many to many relation with activities

Comment: @Uthr, why avoid other simple things.. If you're going to help it's best to point **everything** out so that the Op is aware.

Comment: @Option you have a point, someone else pointed it out that i have to use a controller, so this code is now in a controller, what else is wrong?

Comment: @Thimo, it's good that you're taking point on to lead you on to the right tracks. I'd suggest reviewing the laravel docs about relationships as these will come in handy especially for your current question.

Comment: Also Laracasts is a great place to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You should be making use of Laravel Eloquent many-to-many relationships for this kind of query.

Assuming you're using Laravel 5.5, this documentation entry will help:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Basically, in your model definitions, you should be setting up the relationships. For example, in the Deadline model's definition, you would have something like the following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Deadline extends Model
{
    /**
     * The activities associated with this deadline
     */
    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserActivity');
    }
}
```

If you have this set up for all of your related Models, then you can do things like this:

```
$user = App\User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$activities = $user->activities->whereHas('deadlines', function ($query) {
    $query->where('beginDatum', '<=', $today)->where('eindDatum', '>=', $today;
})->get();
```